# calculating GCD java, why do I keep getting 0?

Tags: java

```
public class gcd1 {

    public static int gcd(int inT, int inU) {
        int t = inT;
        int u = inU;

        if (u == 0) {
            return u;
        }
        return gcd(u, t % u);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(gcd(288, 30));
    }
}
```

I keep getting 0 when I should be getting 6. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: `if (u == 0){ return u; }` Think about what this piece of code does. What values of `u` can possibly be returned?

Comment: Hint, the code should be checking for (t % u) == 0.

Comment: @Rawsick - [it appears you've asked 6 answered questions, but none are accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the wrong variable at line 6 you have

```
if (u == 0){
    return u;
}
```

This should be

```
if (u == 0){
    return t;
}
```

Try this and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the problem is your only `return` is `if (u == 0)`.

You should replace it with `if (t % u == 0)`

In addition, there's no need to reassign the variables passed to the method, so just use `inT` and `inU`:

```
if (inU == 0) {
    return inT;
}
return gcd(inU, inT % inU);
```